# Can setTimeout be set on a onchange event?

Tags: jquery

I want to delay execution of some code after a few seconds.

I guess setTimeout  is the function to be used. Below is the code i have. I just want the timeout_trigger's alert to fire after 2 sec of a change event. The change event alert fires but not the timeout_trigger's

```
function timeout_trigger() {
            alert('time out trigger called');
            alert($(this).attr('id') + ' on change ' + $(this).val());  
        }


 $('input[id$="accountLookup"]').change(function() {
            alert('click function called');
            setTimeout('timeout_trigger()', 2000);

        });
```

What is that i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes:

1. `timeout_trigger` is not defined inside that `setTimeout` string, which seems to have its own scope. Instead of passing a string, pass the function itself to solve *that* problem: `setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000)`.
2. Once the function is called, `this` will refer to the `window` object that called it rather than the element that changed. I'd therefore recommend the following structure:

   ```
    function timeout_trigger() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' on change ' + $(this).val());  
    }

    $('input[id$="accountLookup"]').change(function() {
        // Bind the current `this` to a local variable, so we can access
        // it in the anonymous function below. Then, use
        // `timeout_trigger.call` to bind `element` to its `this` value.
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function () { timeout_trigger.call(element) }, 2000);
    });
   ```

[A live demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/9Py5G/1/) (see the console for output)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes from the function name.

```
function timeout_trigger() {
    alert('time out trigger called');
    alert($(this).attr('id') + ' on change ' + $(this).val());  
}


$('input[id$="accountLookup"]').change(function() {
    alert('click function called');
    setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This will call `timeout_trigger` immediately, rather than after 2000ms.

Comment: Changing `timeout_trigger()` to just `timeout_trigger` will fix the problem.

Comment: Edited as per Matchu / bdesham

Comment: Still broken because of the `this` reference, though. That was a tricky gotcha that I wouldn't have caught without the power of jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Trying removing quotes and parens here `setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000);`.

Maybe the parens are needed but I think not.